# OpenMP implementation

Tags: c++, linux, openmp

I recently began testing some thread libraries on some computationally heavy code. I ran across OpenMP and I am very happy with it's simplicity and speed.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how it's implemented however. I'm guessing it uses pthreads underneath the hood. Does anyone have any information on this subject?

I'm asking because my openmp implementation out performs pure pthreads. I think there must be some false sharing issues but for now I was just wondering what openmp uses underneath the hood since it seems very high level.

Comment: Most linux and MacOS implementations of OpenMP base threading on pthreads.  On Windows, commercial implementations often are based on Windows threads without pthreads, as a pthreads layer (as in libgomp) may show some performance issues, as well as missing some of the current OpenMP features.

Comment: For full documentation of implementations, examination of the gnu libgomp or the openmprtl.org is often suggested.

Comment: @Tim, it may be slightly mean to describe those sites as "full documentation", though perhaps the code counts as the best documentation! Another alternative is http://openmp.llvm.org (which is effectively the same code as at openmprtl.org, but may be slightly ahead of it...). And I know for sure that there's a manual there, though how useful it is may be more questionable!

Comment: In some unix OS distributions, you can download the sources using the OS default package manager. For example, in debian-like distros, you can download the source of libgomp package with `apt source libgomp1` (that actually will download the gcc source). Then extract the source tarball and look for `libgomp` folder